# About adaboost algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, traffic, prediction, adaboost

I'm working on a traffic flow prediction where I can predict that a place has heavy or light traffic. I have classified each traffic as 1-5, 1 being the lightest traffic and 5 being the heaviest traffic.

I came across to this website http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v25/v25-36.pdf, AdaBoost algorithm, and I'm really having a difficulty learning this algorithm.
Specially in the part where `S` is the set ((`xi`, `yi`), `i=(1,2,…,m)`). where `Y={-1,+1}`. What are `x`, `y` and the constant `L`? what is the value of `L`?

Can someone explain me this algorithm? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`S={(x1,y1),...,(xm,ym)}`: Every `(x,y)` pair is a sample used for training (or testing) your classifier:

- `x` = The features which describe this particular sample, for example values which list the `amount of cars on the road`, `day of the week`, etc
- `y` = The label for a particular `x`, which in your case can be `1, 2, 3, 4 or 5`

`Table 1` in the paper shows the `x` features they used , namely: `DAY`, `TIME`, `INT`, `DET`, `LINK`, `POS`, `GRE`, `DIS`, `VOL` and `OCC`. The last column of the table shows the label (`y`), which they set to either `1` or `-1` (i.e., `yes` or `no`). Every row in the table is 1 sample.

`L` is the amount of rounds in which AdaBoost trains a weak learner (in the paper `Random Forests` is used as the weak classifier). If you set `L` to `1` then AdaBoost will run 1 round and only 1 weak classifier will be trained, which will have bad results. Perform multiple experiments with different values for `L` to find the optimal value (i.e., when AdaBoost is converged or when it starts to overfit).